# Rails implementation of search with autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

I am not to sure how to have an autocomplete form to my search function.

```
<%= form_tag "/search", :method => "get" do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query] %>
    <%= image_submit_tag "site/blankimg.png", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

I have a controller of the following which has a customized action

```
   def query
     @users= Search.user(params[:query])
     @article= Search.article(params[:query])
   end
```

The model is has follow:

```
def self.user(search)
 if search
    User.find(:all, :conditions => ['first_name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    User.find(:all)
  end
end

def self.article(search)
  if search
    Article.find(:all, :conditions => ['title LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    Article.find(:all)
  end
end
```

Now this work great for a search but it, i would like it to show me the result has i am writing it, and i can't use jquery autocomplete because it is two object.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use **Twitter typeahead**. There are some examples here:

http://twitter.github.com/typeahead.js/examples/

Twitter typeahead and all the information you need is available from https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/

**How to use**

The use depends on the data you are going to have as 'suggested'. For example, if it is static data (always going to be the same) you can implement it this way:

```
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
  local: ['suggestion1', 'suggestion2', 'suggestion3',...., 'suggestionN']
  #The typeahead is going to load suggestions from data in local.
});
```

If the data changes and it came from a model or a db table then you can try:

```
Controller:
def load_suggestions
  @suggestions = MyModel.select(:name) or MyModel.find(:all, conditions: [...]) #Select the data you want to load on the typeahead.
  render json: @suggestions
end

JS file:
$('input.typeahead').typeahead([
  {
    prefetch: 'https://www.mipage.com/suggestion.json' #route to the method 'load_suggestions'
    #This way, typeahead will prefecth the data from the remote url
   }
]);
```

Comment: how would i hook my model to it?

Comment: thanks, i am reading their api is a bit confusing for first time seen

Comment: You have to download both typeahead.js and typeahead.css files

Comment: Can you confirm gem for Rails 4? Is it `bootstrap-typeahead-rails`? So having simple `<input class="typeahead"...` in views and gem asset enabled should be enough? If I type `sugg` I should be able to see all options: `suggestion1`, `suggestion2`, etc.?