# Using Typeahead with Rails (How to send request from html to controller)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, typeahead.js

So after searching through the previous questions on this topic, I didn't come across one that matched by particular dilemma. I'm trying to use the typeahead.js to autocomplete a search, however, I'm a bit unsure of how to call the search method in my controller once the user hits the submit button (the auto complete does work though).

**HTML**:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group" id="the-basics">
          <input class="typeahead form-control" type="text" placeholder="Seach for Book">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Controller**:

```
  def search
    @books = Book.where("name iLIKE ?","%#{params[:search]}%")
    render :index
  end
```

For reference, I usually go about it this way to getting the search to trigger the method:

```
<div id="the-basics">
    <%= form_tag book_search_path, class: "typeahead", method: "GET" do %>
        <input type = "text" name = "search"/>
        <input type = "submit" name = "GO" value = "Search for Books" />
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191240/rails-implementation-of-search-with-autocomplete

Comment: Hey there, I did check out this question but it doesn't quite answer how I call the request if my form is html (rather than Rail's form_tag).