# How do I create a dropdown list specifically for Indian states and cities?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rubygems

My app is planned to go for only India and I need to add the location information to user profiles. So is there any way to create the dropdowns myself for the states and cities or gems specifically for India.

I mean if I could feed the states and cities myself which I want showing up to the user and then allow him to choose his, how do I do that?

I can't work with the text fields because I want to make the whole thing searchable by locations and if users enter different locations the quality of the search will drastically decrease.

Links to tutorials are also welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

you an use the form [`select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select) helper. if you have all your possible states in activerecord, you can do something like this in your form:

```
<%= f.select :state_id, State.all.collect {|s| [s.name, s.id]} %>
```

if you don't want them in activerecord, i would define an array of that in the model, and feed that to the form.

also, take a look at the [enumerize](https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize), gem, it's useful if you have a finite set of options for a field.

and another thing, there are the [countries](https://github.com/hexorx/countries/blob/master/README.markdown) and [cities](https://github.com/joecorcoran/cities/blob/master/README.md) gems to help you householding the city/country data.

Answer (score 0):

I am now rendering a .json along with the Twitter Typeahead library instead of adding a dropdown. I've uploaded the file to Github for future reference.

Here is a link to the JSON

https://github.com/nshntarora/Indian-Cities-JSON

Here is a link to a SO answer on Typeahead

[Rails implementation of search with autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191240/rails-implementation-of-search-with-autocomplete)